# How to get last part of url in blade file (HTML) using laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am new to laravel.
I want to get the last part of my url in the blade file(HTML file).
I have done this one using php functionality .
Is there any way I can get it using any laravel functionality .

Below is my code ,its working fine

```html
<?php
$url = url()->current();
echo $end = end((explode('/', $url)));
?>
```

I have also used this one to get

```html
Request::segment(2)
```

Here my url is http://localhost/blog/public/user/add-user.
I want to get add-user in the html file.

Thank you

Comment: Last part? .php? Do you just mean the route?

Comment: The questions from me: why You need that? If You are passing some kind of ID - there is other proper ways to do it.

Comment: I have modified my question please check it. @Farkie

Comment: What you are getting when you are using `Request::segment(2)`?

Answer (score 5):

Try this code for getting last value of URL

```
$uri_path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
$uri_parts = explode('/', $uri_path);
$request_url = end($uri_parts);
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is: "No there is not any Laravel functionality" or more precisely Laravel helpers for getting the last segment, but fortunately you can just use php.  The `end` has been mentioned and `end` works on an array, but I don't think it is possible to use directly on `Request::segments()`. That means you have to put `Request::segments()` into a variable (like `$lastSegment`) first and then use `end` on the variable.

The best and slimmest way I could find to do this is:

```
{{ basename(Request::url()) }}
```

Use this in blade, but of course like mentioned before you can add this in the controller or a [Laravel view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers).

Answer (score 1):

```
{{last(request()->segments())}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want the last segment (it may be the 2nd, 3rd, 4th etc) you can use `end(Request::segments())` to conistently always get the last segment.

Also, if you don't want to call functions in your templates and be a bit more 'Laravel' why not bind it to your view from the controller?

In your controller:

```
public function show() 
{
   return view('your.view')->with('lastSegment', end(Request::segments()));
}
```

Then in your view you can do this:

```
<p> The last segment is {{$lastSegment}} </p>
```

Also, if you want to have `$lastSegment` be available in all your views without having to code it in all your controllers, look into using [Laravel's view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#view-composers). Very powerful for making templates.